# What is the equivalent of iOS DSP libs in Android?

Tags: android, ios, signal-processing

In iOS there are super nice APIs for various DSP and image processing functions. (Convolution, 2D filters etc. etc.) It seems these APIs are accelerated and work really well compared to native implementations (based on my experience).

Now I am about to port my App to Android and I couldn't find similar APIs for Android. Are there similar APIs in Android?